# storing variables which are computed in an reactive statement for use in hist()

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

This question is a follow up to:

[Display table and recompute one column based on sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791247/display-table-and-recompute-one-column-based-on-sliders)

I want to catch the computed score (which is only rendered, not stored from what I understood) in a variable so that I can also update the associated histogram, whenever it is computed.

this is the code I have so far:

```
library(shiny)
#### INIT ####
x <- 1
y <- 0.5
z <- 2
df <- data.frame(
  a=1:10,
  b=10:1
)
df['score'] <- df[,x]^y + z
tmp <- reactiveVariable(score=df['score'])

#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x", "x:",
                  min = 0, max = ncol(df),
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("y", "y:",
                  min = 1, max = 10,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("z", "z:",
                  min = 1, max = 100,
                  value = 20),
      hr(),
      wellPanel(style="background:white",
      plotOutput("hist")
  )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("df", dataTableOutput("df"))
      )
    )
  )
)


#### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    df['score'] <- df[,input$x]^input$y + input$z
    tmp$score <- df['score']
    df
   })

  output$df <- renderDataTable(sliderValues())
  output$hist <- renderPlot(hist({tmp$score}))   
}

#### RUN #### 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However this is only giving me the error "hist.default: 'x' must be numeric".
What am I doing wrong? I thought saving to a *reactiveVariable* variable calls the reactive function in which the variable is used (in this case the rendering of the histogram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several issues. Please start with this

```
library(shiny)
#### INIT ####
df <- data.frame(
  a=1:10,
  b=10:1
)

#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x", "x:",names(df)),
      sliderInput("y", "y:",
                  min = 0, max = 10,step = 0.5,
                  value = 0.5),
      sliderInput("z", "z:",
                  min = 1, max = 100,
                  value = 2),
      hr(),
      wellPanel(style="background:white",
                plotOutput("hist")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("df")
    )
  )

)

#### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output) {

  sliderValues <- reactive({
    df$score <- df[,input$x]^input$y + input$z
    df
  })

  output$df <- renderDataTable({sliderValues()})
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(sliderValues()$score)})   
}

#### RUN #### 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I wanted to have the histogram in the sidebar for a better use of space. I actually found a solution myself now. What I haven't mentioned for simplicity reasons was that I also have a tabulated setup, where each tab should display the same content but access different data. I will post my solution as answer.

Comment: I marked your answer as solution. What helped me was the fact that 'sliderValues()' acutally returns the dataframe although there is no return statement. That wasn't clear to me. Thank you!